# Strange behaviour on logout when more than one tab is open

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I'm developing a MVC web application which can integrate Owin authentication (Microsoft Azure and Office 365). I have noticed a strange behaviour on login and logout if the user opens more than one tab. Here are the step:

1. User login
2. User open a menu link in another tab
3. User logout from one of the tab
4. User clicks on any of the menu link on the other tab and he is redirected to MS login page

Here is some code:

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = ClientId,
            Authority = Authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = PostLogoutRedirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

**Logout Method**

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    .....
}
```

The LogOut is executed via AJAX call.

How can I solve my issue?

Comment: That isn't unusual - that is how the web normally works. Which bit _specifically_ are you confused by?

Comment: I cannot understand why the second tab opens the MS login page and not my web application login page. It should go this way if I don't login via external service. Am I wrong?